# JavaScript: How to set a property for a function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, function, properties, mocking

I'm testing one of my functions, and I want to test whether a specific function is called with the right argument from that code.

For that reason, I overwrite the original function like this:

```
var oldSort = sort;
sort = function(array) {
    this.arrayToSort = array;
}
```

Then I execute it and check that the property `sort.arrayToSort` is set to the value I passed in and reassign the original function:

```
sort(myArray);
deepEqual(myArray, sort.arrayToSort); 
sort = oldSort;
```

However, I can't access `sort.arrayToSort` like that. How can I set a property of the function to make that possible? Right now, I'm declaring a variable above the sort function and have it set that, but I'd rather have it as a property of the function to keep its scope small. Is that possible?

Comment: Is that your own deepEqual function or are you using some javascript library?  What Line is causing problem?  Could you include the full javascript instead of theses two snippets.

Comment: I'm using QUnit and this is a test case. I wrote this snippet to reproduce a problem I'm having in our production system whose code I cannot release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want `arguments.callee`, which refers to the function itself, rather than the object it was bound to.

```
var oldSort = sort;
sort = function(array) {
    arguments.callee.arrayToSort = array;
}
```

Comment: Great, this works! But it does look a little obscure - would you recommend doing it this way in my case?

Comment: The other way to do it would be to reference sort directly (sort.arrayToSort = array). arguments.callee is the only way to do it on an anonymous function.

Comment: I don't know if there's a JS mocking library that supports mocking global functions, but that's basically what you're trying to do. If you can find a way to use a mock library, that's what I would recommend.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to mock a global function here, but I'm not sure about adding a 3rd party mocking framework.

Comment: I guess I'll either keep it the way it is or introduce Sinon.JS, seems to work well with QUnit. Anyway, you answered my question so I'll accept :)

Answer (score 0):

you cant access the function properties if you don't create it with new keyword.

```
mysort = new sort(array);
alert(mysort.arrayToSort);
```

you can use custom comparator function in original sort. like this

```
array.sort(sortfunction)

function sortfunction(a, b){
   //Compare "a" and "b" in some fashion, and return -1, 0, or 1
}
```

Comment: Works as well, but similarly obscure. As I asked Austin: Would you recommend doing this in my case?

Comment: I just don't understand why override the original sort? you can write your own sort function and pass it to sort as argument. I'll update my post to make it clear.

Comment: Sorry, I guess the example was pretty bad, I'm assuming the sort function was defined by me.